# EXT4-fs error (device md0) in ext4_free_inode:357: Filesystem failed CRC

Tags: debian, filesystems, kernel

After setting up Raid1 Mirror on DNS server, now I am planning to go for a Debian upgrade from 10 to 11.

I was able to update the source.list file and perform `apt update` but when i do `apt full-upgrade` it fails and when I checked the syslog it shows error as

```
EXT4-fs error (device md0): ext4_validate_inode_bitmap:100: comm dpkg: corrupt inode bitmap -block_group = 0,inode_bitmap = 1043                                                                                                                                             Aborting journal on device md0-8
EXT4-fs error (device md0) in ext4_free_inode:357: Filesystem failed CRC
Aug  2 12:39:07 localhost kernel: [2141055.420335] EXT4-fs error (device md0) in ext4_evict_inode:351: IO failure
```

Can someone help in fixing this

Comment: Obvious first comment is obvious: have you tried to `fsck /dev/md0`?

Comment: @tsc_chazz no, i haven't tried that yet....Can it be run on the running system wthout unmounting?

Comment: @tsc_chazz  i attempted to run fsck /dev/md0 and it asked to reboot which i did and  shows this on screen                                         
                                                                                                                             
 booting from hard disk..                                                                                          boot failed: not a bootable disk....                                                                                                                                          no bootable device retry in 1 second

Comment: It looks like the upgrade attempt may have been thwarted by a failing disk or by a `grub` install failure. Strong suggestion: find a live disk (probably a bootable USB stick), probably best Debian 10, and use that to try troubleshooting the RAID array and boot filesystem.

Comment: @tsc_chazz the sda partition table got deleted ....i selected the boot from sdb and for now the system boots up....how to get back the sda partition? i tried sfdisk and it recovered but it hangs at reboot..may be i am doing wrong or somethng missing

Comment: I think at this point we're in new question territory. While I think I know what I'd do, I also know this is an area where I'd be kind of fumbling, it's probably time to hunt someone more knowledgeable in this area.

Comment: Guys are you all blind? The harddisks are failing cause of hardware malfunction. OP has probably lost (maybe even all) data. If it was important data, power off your machine immediately and bring your harddisks to a professional data recovery company. Otherwise throw the harddisks into trash and buy new ones.

Comment: paladin has a fair point, though it may be only sda that's failing.